# I don't know how to write the character: È

Tags: word-processing

I want to write the character: È.
I've already tried Alt + 0200, as suggested on many website, but it doesn't work. Maybe it works on Windows but I'm on linux debian. I do not want to copy and paste each time.

BTW: I can write É by pressing <kbd>Alt gr</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd> and then releasing and pressing Shift e, but unfortunately not È.

Comment: I use the US-International keyboard layout/driver, which makes it easy - simply type backquote (on the same key as `~`, usually - I can never get it to appear as a code insert...), then `E`.

Comment: depends on which keyboard layout you're using

Answer (score 1):

In Linux you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>u</kbd> followed by the code in hex. (You only need to hold down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd> while typing the code)

You can find the codes here https://r12a.github.io/app-conversion/, look at the U+hex part.

Example:

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd> <kbd>0</kbd> <kbd>0</kbd> <kbd>c</kbd> <kbd>8</kbd> <kbd>ENTER</kbd>

results in È.

The Linux console also supports compose keys (The compose key is often <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>AltGr</kbd> or <kbd>PrintScrn</kbd>) - see [How to define a Compose Key in terminal](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/44478) on the Unix and Linux Stack Exchange for details.

Alternatively, switch to a layout with [dead keys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_key) and this will let you enter accents using AltGr (right alt key). For example:

- <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>'</kbd> and then <kbd>i</kbd> gives `í`;

Comment: the hex code for that character is: UTF-8 (hex) = 0xC3 0x88 (c388), but it does't work Ctrl + Shift + c388, or what should I type exaclty?

Comment: You should type 00c8 for uppercase  or 00e9 for lowercase, added it to the answer

Comment: Ok so I have to take the UTF-16 (hex): 0x00C8 (00c8)

Answer (score 0):

I use a UK keyboard on Ubuntu (a Debian derivative). I patiently went through every <kbd>AltGr</kbd> with and without <kbd>Shift</kbd>. Most combinations produce a single character immediately, but a few produce diacriticals, which add an accent to the next character typed.

In the table below, the first line is the character required, and the second line is the character to type in combination with the <kbd>AltGr</kbd> key, or <kbd>AltGr</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd> keys.

Note that when <kbd>Shift</kbd> is used, it must be pressed *after* <kbd>AltGr</kbd>.

For the diacriticals in the table I have had to type another character to make them visible: it should be obvious which I have used.

```
Alternative Graphics:
Chars   ¹²³ €½¾ æ”¢ ðđŋ ħ→ĸ łµø þ¶ß ŧ↓“ ł»← «·
AltGr   123 456 abc dfg hik lmo prs tuv wxy z.

Alternative Graphics, THEN Shift:
Chars   ¡⅛£ ¼⅜⅝ ⅞™± °¿Æ ’©Ð ªŊĦ ıŁº ØÞΩ ®§Ŧ ↑‘Ł ¥¿× ÷
AltGrSh 123 456 789 0-a bcd fgh ilm opq rst uvw y-, .

Diacriticals:
Chars   çöó ôòọ ỏ
AltGr   =[; '#/ j

Chars   åōő ǒŏȯ ơ
AltGrSh []; '#/ j
```

So for your `È` character I need to type <kbd>AltGr</kbd><kbd>#</kbd>, then release and type <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>E</kbd>.

From the example you quote of the effect of <kbd>AltGr</kbd><kbd>,</kbd>, you clearly have a different keyboard from me, so you will need to hunt around for the key combination for your keyboard. As a starting point, my <kbd>#</kbd> key is the rightmost key on the third row up from the bottom, ie two above the row with the space-bar - your required key *may* be in the same physical position.